# VirtualBox Lab & IPtables rules

Tags: server, firewall

I want to create this lab to apply the rules of iptables on the network, how I selected IP addresses for each interface and each sub-networks to create this lab?

Please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Link Internet: This will more than likely be DHCP'ed from your router. If not you will need a 'local IP' and set the gateway to the internet.

Link Teachers: a 192.168.x.x subnet will do the trick. as this is a lab, you could use 192.168.1.x/24

Link DMZ: Same as Teachers link use 192.168.2.x/24

Link Students: Same as Teachers Link use 192.168.3.x/24

Of course if you have more than 254 devices on the subnet, then you will need to increase the range.

If you only have 1 network card, then you will need to bind an IP address from each subnet to the network card - binding multiple IPs [source](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface).

Once you have your interfaces and networks setup, you should be able use IPTABLES.